# How do I fix memory allocation problem with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

little background, I've inherited a piece of code in company that is written in Python, which I don't really know, the code is combining few pre-downloaded Excel reports into one using pandas. I keep running into Memory Allocation Error:

***MemoryError: Unable to allocate 368. MiB for an array with shape (17, 5668350) and data type object***

This is the code that gives me the error:

```
dfCC = dfVendNew.merge(dfVendOld[['SAP ID', 'Cost ctr']], on='SAP ID', how='left')
```

I am stuck on this point unable to progress further. I've tried changing the paging size on Windows but it did not help. I suspect that it is related to my computer settings since this script is running on the other machines without a hitch.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You probably need more RAM...

The more qualified answer depends on the data, the actual dataframe and what's else loaded in RAM in your project

Comment: I've checked my RAM usage doesn't go above 7 GB out of 31,8 GB available

Comment: 32-bit Python (or 32-bit OS which would require 32-bit Python) would mean you are restricted to 4G max memory available for Python - are you using 64-bit Python on 64-bit OS?

Comment: Oh no, I think you might have found solution to my issue, let me just check how it behaves on 64 bit version since I am currently using 32 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are going to be the fattest way to store lists of things.  But you need to know a bit about how something is stored in order to make it smaller and faster.
Check out the column types using dataframe's `df.info()`

This is a toy example:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
people     3 non-null object
cost_ctr    3 non-null object
number     3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 152.0+ bytes
```

In this case people is an object class and so is message.  The other thing to look at is on the last line: memory usage. So now you'll be able to change your data types and watch your memory usage drop. So let's go through how to change some of these types.

Your SAP_ID is probably an int by default.  If it is not and it's all numeric data you can use:

```
df['SAP ID']=df['SAP ID'].astype(int)
```

or

```
df['SAP ID']=pd.to_numeric(df['SAP ID'])
```

so now that you have changed a type of one column check out the memory with `df.info()` again.

"Cost ctr" sounds like it's going to be a short list of things that repeats a lot,  but is generally stored as a list of strings.  You could change this column to a pd.categorical and see how much memory you save with this command.

```
df['Cost_Ctr'] = df['Cost_Ctr'].astype(pd.Categorical)
```

Check out the documentation for using [astype here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)
a next level move would be importing it correctly in the first place. When you read the excel file use the [converters argument in read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel#pandas.read_excel).

If getting your memory usage down still is a problem (this shouldn't be with only Excel records) there are other distributed technologies you can use for this purpose namely [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-joins.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the data from those files is indeed very strangely structured so I will sure need to take a look at that. However my issue was a result of running 32 bit Python on 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 4):

You can try processing and merging the dataframes in chunks, here is my attempt:

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
new = dfVendNew
old = dfVendOld[['SAP ID', 'Cost ctr']]
    for sap_id in np.array_split(new['SAP ID'].unique(), 10):
         new_chunk = new[new['SAP ID'].isin(sap_id)]
         old_chunk = old[old['SAP ID'].isin(sap_id)]
         merged = new_chunk.merge(old_chunk, on='SAP ID', how='left')
         all_data = pd.concat([merged, all_data], ignore_index=True, sort=False)

        del new_chunk
        del old_chunk
        del merged

    return all_data
```

First you get unique SAP ID's of your new dataframe, then you create 10 different lists of SAP ID's, then you split both new and old dataframes based on those lists. Merge each chunk and `del` to relieve your memory.

Comment: Hi Onur, thank you for your response, I've tried implementing this, Error message changed to:

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 241. MiB for an array with shape (18, 3511836) and data type object

It broke on 6th loop, those del isntructions should be outside of the for loop yes?

Comment: Hi Tomasz, del should be inside of the for loop because the loop creates chunks, merges them, appends to all_data and after that it has no use for those chunks so it deletes those objects to relieve memory for each iteration.
For your new error message I think a critical factor might be how your SAP ID's distribute across data for example if %80 of your rows contain %10 of your SAP ID's then splitting dataframes based on unique SAP ID's does not make much sense since it will lead to unbalanced chunks. Would love to hear more about how your SAP ID's distribute across your data, thanks.